# Version checking in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I am trying to update database table's rows using Hibernate.

Do I need to write any code for getting the old version and then comparing it with latest version of rows in a database table to avoid Stale Object Updation Exception while using Hibernate?

OR

versioning is  handled automatically by Hibernate?

Comment: It should be automatically handled by hibernate.

Comment: docs: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#locking

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are trying use `optimistic` locking and the version number mechanism for `optimistic locking` is provided through a `@Version` annotation like below:

```
@Version
private long version;
```

From docs:

> Here, the version property is mapped to the version column, and the
>   entity manager uses it to detect conflicting updates, and prevent the
>   loss of updates that would otherwise be overwritten by a
>   last-commit-wins strategy.

The hibernate will take care of `version` automatically. The correspond documentation for reference:

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#locking

Adding an example

main class:

```
public class HibernateVersionMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;
        Session session = null;
        Transaction tx = null;
        sessionFactory = HibernateAnnotationUtil.getSessionFactory();
        session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        Cart2 cart = new Cart2();
        cart.setName("test cart1");
        tx= session.beginTransaction();
        session.saveOrUpdate(cart);

        tx.commit();
        //session.close();
        session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        Cart2 cart2 = (Cart2) session.get(Cart2.class, 1l);
        cart2.setName("test cart1 changed");

        session.saveOrUpdate(cart2);
        tx.commit();
        //session.close();
    }
```

Entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CART1")
public class Cart2 {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="cart_id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name="total")
    private double total;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @Version
    private int version;

    public int getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(int version) {
        this.version = version;
    }



    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public double getTotal() {
        return total;
    }
    public void setTotal(double total) {
        this.total = total;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Cart1 [id=" + id + ", total=" + total + ", name=" + name + "]";
    }

 }
```

From the logs:

> INFO: HHH000232: Schema update complete Hibernate: insert into CART1
>   (name, total, version) values (?, ?, ?)
>
> Hibernate: select cart2x0_.cart_id as cart_id1_1_0_, cart2x0_.name as
>   name2_1_0_, cart2x0_.total as total3_1_0_, cart2x0_.version as
>   version4_1_0_ from CART1 cart2x0_ where cart2x0_.cart_id=?
>
> Hibernate: update CART1 set name=?, total=?, version=? where cart_id=?
>   and version=?

The database tables (Have a look at `version` column check the main code):

[image]

[image]